# How do I save and load a custom object in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, save, load

I've been teaching myself PowerShell and have been trying to save a custom object to a file so that it can be reloaded later. However, all of the methods I've found online are returning an array of strings rather than an object of the class I saved.

Let's say I have an object `$testObject` of custom class `TestClass`. I want to save `$testObject` to a file (I've been using a text file, but I really don't care what kind of file it is) and I want to reload it again later as a `TestClass` object of the same value.

I have tried both `$testObject > $filePath` and `Out-File -FilePath $filePath-InputObject $testObject` both save what the terminal output would be for `$testObject`. I then use `Get-Content $filePath` to load the object again but instead of a `TestClass` object, I get an array of strings. Does anyone know how to do this? Is it even possible?

Comment: You can use `Export-CliXml` for this but note that after importing, the object will no longer be a `TestClass` instance, it will be a `Deserialized.TestClass` instance. All methods from your class will be ripped off.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].